# Intercepting the Windows file system, editing data?

Tags: c++, c, windows, file

How could I intercept, in Windows 7, deletion of files programatically, and modify the memory being deleted, so it is random?

From what I have heard, Windows doesn't actually delete files, but deletes the references to them  It is not actually until you write over the memory with 0's that the data is no longer recoverable.

What I want to do, is a less memory dependent solution. Instead of when I go into a program for 'fully' deleting a file, I want to do it automatically through the Windows filesystem. When a delete event is called (I'm not sure about the correct terminology, so correct me if I'm wrong), I want to randomly set some of the memory to 0.

I assume this would be possible in C++, using the WinAPI.  Are there higher level programming languages that would accomplish this as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd probably need a kernel driver to catch *everything* and manage it efficiently.

there are a few samples in the Windows DDK on creating filesystem interaction drivers, the best ones being in `WinDDK\7600.16385.1\src\filesys\miniFilter`. also in the `filesys` folder are some sample for the various filesystems used under windows, nothing on NTFS though...